# Proving double inequalities using well-ordering property

Tags: proof-explanation, well-orders

I was given a proposition: $∀x ∈ R$, if $0 < x < 1$, then $∃ n ∈ N$, $\frac1n < x \le \frac {1}{n-1}$. I understand that the well-ordering property states that for a set $S ∈ Z$, if $S$ is a non-zero set, and $x ∈ S$, then there is an element
$a ∈ S$ such that $a \le x$. However, I don't get how that property can be used to prove a proposition such as this one. Can someone please explain how to use the well-ordering property?

Comment: Where did the "m" come from? Did you mean"1/(n-1}"?

Comment: yes sorry, I meant to say n

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that
this is what you want to prove:

For $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$,
let
$R(n)
=\{x | \frac1{n+1} < x \le \frac1{n}\}
$.

Then,
$0 < x \le 1
\implies
\exists n \in \mathbb{N}^+
$ with
$x \in R(n)
$.

Here is my proof
(as usual, off the top of my head
with editing as I go).

Since
$0 < x \le 1$,
$1 \le \frac1{x}$.
Let $y  = \frac1{x}$.

By the axiom of Archimedes.
there is an integer $m$
such that
$m \gt y$.

Let 
$G(y)
=\{m | m \gt y\}
$.

We have shown that
$G(y)$ is non-empty.

Also,
all integers $j \le 1$
are not in $G(y)$.

By the well-ordering principle,
$G(y)$ has a smallest member.
Call this $k$.

For this,
we must have
$k \gt y$
and
$k-1 \le y$.

Therefore
$\frac1{k} < \frac1{y} \le \frac1{k-1}$
or
$\frac1{k} < x \le \frac1{k-1}$,
so that
$x \in R(k)$.

And we are done.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the real number system $\mathbb R$ implies that there is no $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $0<x\leq q$ for every positive rational $q.$  (It is possible to extend $\mathbb R$ to a larger number-field in which such $x$ do exist.)

One of the consequences is that if $0<x\in \mathbb R$ then there exists $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $n> 1/x.$

Otherwise for any $q\in \mathbb Q^+$ we have $q=m/n$ for some $m,n\in \mathbb N,$  and $n\leq 1/x,$ so $q=m/n\geq 1/n\geq x$. But this cannot be true for every $q\in \mathbb Q$.

So for $0<x<1$ let $n_0$ be the least $n\in \mathbb N $ such that $n> 1/x.$ Then $n_0>1$ because $1/x>1.$ We have $$(\bullet )\quad n_0> 1/x\geq n_0-1$$  by def'n of $n_0.$..... And $n_0-1\in \mathbb N$ because $n_0>1.$ So $n_0-1>0$, so $(\bullet)$ is equivalent  to $$1/n_0<x\leq 1/(n_0-1).$$